# Orchard multi-level dropdown on click only

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, razor, orchardcms

I am working with Orchard on an Bootstrap based theme. The menu navigation CSS code looks like this and is working fine when hovering over the second level menu.

```
.dropdown-menu .dropdown-menu {
  left: 100% !important;
  top: 0;
}

.dropdown .dropdown:hover > .dropdown-menu,
.dropdown .dropdown .dropdown:hover > .dropdown-menu,
.dropdown .dropdown .dropdown .dropdown:hover > .dropdown-menu {
  display: block;
}

.dropdown-menu i {
  line-height: 1.42857143;
}
```

Now, I would like for all levels of this drop-down menu to open only on click because this is not working on touch-based devices. When i change ':hover's to :focus, everything closes when second level `nav-bar` is clicked. I am really not a skilled html/css coder, so I'm not really sure how this works. I presume `dropdown` is name of the `ul` class and `dropdown-menu` of `div` this menu is located in, but am not sure since all the code is generated... Also, I'm sorry for my not so great in English.
Thanks.

Comment: try to this $('.dropdown .dropdown').on('click', function(){
$(this).find('.dropdown-menu').show();
});

Comment: Well, since this is not a regular html but cshtml, I have written your code in my custom.js file, but it is not working ... should I also change my css code?

Comment: I got Orchard to execute your js but it opens the second and third level under whole navigation (under orange line on image) and i closes it inside of the navigation.

this is how my navigation looks like...
http://www.image-share.com/ipng-3142-278.html

and this is nav-bar hierarchy in my html..
http://ShareText.net/tBb.html

Answer (score 0):

As you can see in this example:
http://codepen.io/HerrSerker/details/wMdgER/
`:focus` does not work, because you cannot bubble with CSS3- like you can do with `:hover` and you can only have one element with `:focus`. So you do not have a `:focus` memory

The soultion is to build a workaround with something that has a memory. You should use radio buttons with the `:checked` selector and adjacent combinator (`A + B`).

See here: http://codepen.io/HerrSerker/pen/obWBVG

You then have to hide the radio buttons and let the labels do the work

```css
nav ul label {
  display: block;
}
nav ul > li > label > input:checked + ul {
  display: block;
}
nav ul.lvl-2 {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <ul class="lvl-1">
    <li>
      <label for="id-lvl1-01">
        <input type="radio" name="lvl-1" id="id-lvl1-01" />1
        <ul class="lvl-2">
          <li>
            <label for="id-lvl2-01-01">
              <input type="radio" name="lvl-1-1" id="id-lvl2-01-01" />01</label>
          </li>
          <li>
            <label for="id-lvl2-01-02">
              <input type="radio" name="lvl-1-1" id="id-lvl2-01-02" />02</label>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </label>
    </li>
    <li>
      <label for="id-lvl1-02">
        <input type="radio" name="lvl-1" id="id-lvl1-02" />2
        <ul class="lvl-2">
          <li>
            <label for="id-lvl2-02-01">
              <input type="radio" name="lvl-1-2" id="id-lvl2-02-01" />01</label>
          </li>
          <li>
            <label for="id-lvl2-02-02">
              <input type="radio" name="lvl-1-2" id="id-lvl2-02-02" />02</label>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </label>
    </li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: Thank you for your response, but I can't edit html in Orchard because it is generated at startup. I tried to put parts of your code as html in my drop-down menu items, but Orchard is generating some code in between of them :/. CSS is definitely out of the question?

Comment: If you have no control over the output your CMS makes, then it is a bad CMS. I don't know nothing about Orchanrd. You should investigate, if you can change the menu output from Orchard

Comment: I think you have to change the theme: http://docs.orchardproject.net/Documentation/Anatomy-of-a-theme#ShapeTemplates

Comment: Of course, Orchard lets you modify every single tag it emits. It's just a matter of knowing what templates to edit. Look in the navigation module to see what templates you can override in your theme.